# Problems with knife tool

Tags: mesh, knife-tool

I'm having some problems with the knife tool, sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't.

I would like to cut the shape of the lingerie texture at the body but the knife tool works at some places and doesn't work at others

I've already removed the doubles and verified if has a face.

[20s video of what happens](https://i.imgur.com/UdW3419.mp4)

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18b3cXLCcPxlAHdq-HBznhkrdnLKjj8QV/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: it seems to work fine here, both with 2.79 or 2.9, do you press Enter when you create the last vertex?

Comment: Yes.. I pressed enter. It works ok at some parts and doesn't work at others.. so annoying. I used the 2.70, I'll try 2.79. Thanks

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot! It works on 2.79!

Comment: oh ok so maybe the tool was improved in 2.79

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. If you found a solution for your problem please write it on the 
answers section and mark it as accepted there. Read: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.
stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works.